# Win 10 Laptop with full HD display: why do some programs appear grainy

Tags: windows-10, display

I recently moved to my first laptop with a Full HD display. Everything looks great but some programs (e.g. pdf architect) appear grainy.

This is on Win 10. Is there a setting etc. that may be affecting resolution in some programs? Is it just that the programs cannot handle this higher resolution or is there anything that I could change in the settings to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just that the programs cannot handle this higher resolution

That's the problem.

You have display scaling enabled, so that things on your screen aren't tiny despite pixels being much smaller physically. Display scaling needs special support in programs to work correctly.

Programs that are scaling-aware will take advantage of scaling. Others draw their window in a buffer as if scaling was disabled and Windows upscales them afterwards. The result is similar to zooming in on a photo, they become blurry.

You can disable scaling on per-application basis in properties of the EXE or a shortcut, on the *Compatibility* tab. You can also disable it altogether for entire system in *Display settings*. This will increase available screen area at the cost of everything getting smaller.

Comment: Thanks! So I tried that but does not seem to fix it. What does work is if I go to the global windows properties and set scaling to 100% (it was at 125% the reccomended default for my Laptop). However that has the undesired side effect of affecting all the other programs on my Laptop as well. Is there any way to selectively have this 100% scaling effect just for this program and leave the global setting at 125%? Not sure how to do that.

Comment: @curious_cat _What_ does not seem to fix it? The compatibility setting is the way to set 100% scaling per app.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I am not doing it right. Could you again elaborate on which setting on an app specific basis you reccomend? I did go into properties and compatibility settings but I don't find an explicit 100% option there.